# Why is jQuery not inserting new html based on attribute selectors?

Tags: jquery, css, attributes

This is embarrassing, but here goes. Here's the page that I'm working on: [www.mchenry.edu/administration/BoardSchedule.asp](http://www.mchenry.edu/administration/BoardSchedule.asp)

I'm using jQuery ver. 1.3.1 and I'm putting tiger stripes on the table. All is well. However, I want to insert a FileInfo class after all .pdf file extensions in the document, so users know they are selecting a PDF. Here's my little fileinfo.js jQuery snippet:

```
$(function(){
    $('<span class="FileInfo"> PDF </span>').insertAfter('li a[href$=.pdf]');
});
```

Why isn't it working? Is it something silly? This snippet works on other pages, just not here. What's going on?

Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for all the `a` elements under a `LI` element, if you want to use it on the links of your table, you should change your selector:

```
$('td a[href$=.pdf]').after('<span class="FileInfo"> PDF </span>');
```

Comment: I feel like such a dolt. Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want to do is...

```
$(function(){
    $('table a[href$=.pdf]').after('<span class="FileInfo">PDF</span>');
});
```

Btw, why not to use just CSS instead?

```
table .pdf:after, table [href$=.pdf]:after {
    content: " PDF";
}
```

Comment: what's the difference in this and "insertafter"? don't they both do the same except the selector and the contents locations are switched

Comment: yup...

"This operation is, essentially, the reverse of doing a regular $(A).after(B), in that instead of inserting B after A, you're inserting A after B."

http://api.jquery.com/